# Managing multiple customer databases in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, multi-tenant

I am building an application that requires separate SQL Server databases for each customer.

To achieve this, I need to be able to create a new customer folder, put a copy of a prototype database in the folder, change the name of the database, and attach it as a new "database instance" to SQL Server.  The prototype database contains all of the required table, field and index definitions, but no data records.  I will be using SMO to manage attaching, detaching and renaming the databases.

In the process of creating the prototype database, I tried attaching a copy of the database (companion .MDF, .LDF pair) to SQL Server, using Sql Server Management Studio, and discovered that SSMS expects the database to reside in

```
c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabaseName.MDF
```

Is this a "feature" of SQL Server?  Is there a way to manage individual databases in separate directories?  Or am I going to have to put all of the customer databases in the same directory? (I was hoping for a little better control than this).

NOTE: I am currently using SQL Server Express, but for testing purposes only.  The production database will be SQL Server 2008, Enterprise version.  So "User Instances" are not an option.

Comment: This directory is propably base directory of your instance, but you can add mdf files from every location that currently logged in sql server user has access to. If you can't see files from SSMS, there is propably problem with file rights. Try running SMSS as administrator, look that everything works fine and then wrk on file rights, so it is accessible for normal user.

Comment: @LukLed: I have access to the files in their new directory, but when I try to attach them using SSMS, it gives me the error that it can't find those files in the base directory.

Comment: How do you log into SSMS? Windows authentication? There are no technical barriers in attaching files from every location, so you propably have to find solution somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The MDF has in it the table containing the physical path of all the database files, as they were on the instance it was detached from. You can overwrite the location(s) during the attach operation:

```
CREATE DATABASE <dbname>
 ON (name=dbfilelogicalname, filename='c:\myNewPath\dbfilename.mdf'),
 (name=dbfile2logicalname, filename='c:\myNewPath\dbfilename2.ndf'),
 (name=dbloglogicalname, filename='c:\myNewPath\dblogfilename.ldf')
 FOR ATTACH;
```

Comment: So you think the problem is just with SSMS, and that if I use SMO to attach, I won't have the same problem?

Comment: SSMS, as well as SMO, has the ability to attach the database file(s) at arbitrary locations. You need to add in the attach dialog all the database files: the MDF, all NDFs and the LDF.